# Useless, [shutdown] is

Tags: discussion, tags

Kill [shutdown](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/shutdown), we should.

Comment: Approve, I think, the Council, of Jedi, does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Comment: This should be done. Let's keep an eye on it until it dies a terrible death.

Comment: I'm an idiot. It's not dead, I was filtering by unanswered.